# search field in List @IndexedEmbedded

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have an entity that has a list of entities, i added `@IndexedEmbedded` in this list to be able to search into it. So i want to search all entities that has the id 123 and the attribute x equals a given value. I tried with the code bellow but i have this error

> Unable to find field bEntity.x in com.xx.xx.AEntity

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class AEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<BEntity> bEntity;
    
}


@Entity
@IdClass(BPK.class)
public class BEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Field(name = "x_number")
    private String x;

    @Id
    @Field(name = "y_number")
    private String y;
    
}

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(AEntity.class).get();    
Query query = queryBuilder.bool()
            .must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("id").matching("123").createQuery())
            .must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("bEntity.x").matching(str).createQuery())
            .createQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field is called `bEntity.x_number`, not `bEntity.x`:

```
    @Field(name = "x_number")
```

That's why you're getting this error.

Use `bEntity.x_number` instead of `bEntity.x` in your query and you should be fine.